# Can I disable an account in mysql after x failed login attempts?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, security, logins

I would like to disable accounts after x failed login attempts. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

Also you can use fail2ban for this goal as too easily way . In this case you just install it on you linux OS, then enable the section for `[mysqld-iptables]` in the /etc/fail2ban/jail.local.

```
[mysqld-iptables]
enabled  = true
filter   = mysqld-auth
action   = iptables[name=mysql, port=3306, protocol=tcp]
       sendmail-whois[name=MySQL, dest=root, sender=fail2ban@example.com]
logpath  = /var/log/mysqld.log
maxretry = 5
```

This program check the mysql logs by its own given pattern and then blocks the IP addresses which they try to login more than 5 times, in **iptables**.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using auditing  logon failure event and using triggers for failure event 
,Please have a look at the link
[Audit logins on MySQL database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/668/audit-logins-on-mysql-database/1434#1434)
The locking of account may be handling at active directory locking level