# How to find when the user last logged in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to find all the users when they last logged in in mysql. My goal is to cleanup users that are not used for months. Please help

Comment: Mysql version 5.7.25. When i ran the SELECT plugin from mysql.user , I got 'mysql_native_password'

Comment: Also i am looking for all the users including application users.

Comment: What kind of application is this?

Answer (score 0):

mysql hasn't such a thing.
You could force the users to change the password every 90 days and select the date, where the users didn't change their password.

By

```
SELECT User FROM mysql.user WHERE password_last_changed <  NOW() - INTERVAL  3 MONTH;
```

Everything else would require things like enable file logs see for [more information](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/668/audit-logins-on-mysql-database)